# Changing date based on input field

Tags: jquery

I want to change date based on following situations:-

**Situation 1:-**
If I select "From" date as example: (2014-12-7), the "To" date will be the same as "From".

**Situation 2:-**
If user want to change the date and select "To" date it clear off the date of "To".

**Here is my code:**

```
<script>
var holidays = ['2014/5/1', '2014/8/31', '2014/12/26'];

function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(holidays[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
            return [true, 'highlight'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}

$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+60D",
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        showAnim: "fold",
        inline: false,
        numberOfMonths: [1,2],
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#datepicker1").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        },
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        beforeShowDay: setCustomDate // <-----change function
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+60D",
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        showAnim: "fold",
        inline: false,
        numberOfMonths: [1,2],
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#datepicker").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        },
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        beforeShowDay: setCustomDate // <-----change function
    });
});

function fillDate() {
    datevalue = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
    document.getElementById('datepicker1').value= datevalue; 
}

var disabledDays = ['2014/5/1', '2014/8/31', '2014/12/26'];
    function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
        var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
        for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
            if($.inArray(y + '/' + (m+1) + '/' + d,disabledDays) != -1) {
                return [false];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    }
$(function() {
        $( "#availability" ).datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
            inline: true,
            numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
        });
    });

function setCustomDate(date) {
    var clazz = "";
    var arr1 = highlightDays(date);
    if (arr1[1] != "") clazz = arr1[1];

    var arr2 = disableAllTheseDays(date);
    var arr3 = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);

    return [(!arr2[0] || !arr3[0]) ? false : true, clazz];
}   
</script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="dp" onchange="fillDate(this.form)" readonly name="leavefromdate" value="From" required>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="dp1" onclick="this.value='';"  readonly name="leavetodate" value="To" required>
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue with your code ?

Comment: @dreamweiver
It doesn't change the value of the "To" input field when I change the "From" input field.